# How to check which popup is set to chrome extension?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, browserify

I am sending a message from **webpage** to the **chrome extension**, after getting a response in background.js, I opened chrome extension in a new window. But I want to check whether the user has already login or not. So, I want to check which popup is set in chrome extension, whatever popup has been set I will open that popup HTML in a window.

I tried,

```
chrome.browserAction.getPopup(object details, function callback)
```

but I am not getting exactly which parameters to set here. As I am not using tabId anywhere.

`background.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request);
    window.open("popup.html", "CIC Notification", "width=357,height=600,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no");
});
```

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "CIC Wallet",
  "description": "The CIC Wallet in your browser",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "Image/CI_logo-01.png",
   "default_popup": "setpassword.html"
  },
  "icons": { "16": "Image/CI_logo-01.png",
    "48": "Image/CI_logo-01.png",
   "128": "Image/CI_logo-01.png" 
  },
  "background":{
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["http://127.0.0.1:5501/main.html"]
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "popup.js", "background.js"
    ],
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab","http://127.0.0.1:5501/main.html","tabs"
   ]
}
```

Comment: getPopup() is useful only when you change the popup with setPopup() so since you don't - it's not useful here. I think you can store the state in `localStorage` or in [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Comment: You mean storing the popup HTML file name in storage every time I change it.

Comment: No, not the popup name, but "whether the user has already login or not".

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: BTW, `window.open` is not related to browserAction popup, these are different things.

Comment: Actually, I want to open the chrome extension popup from the webpage with data sent by the webpage. I did not get any solution for that, so opened it in a new window with a particular size.

Comment: You can get a list of open popup windows using chrome.tabs.query({url: chrome.runtime.getURL('*.html'), windowType: 'popup'}, tabs => { .......... })